# Simple JSON stays undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I have an AJAX call that get's a simple JSON back on success, writing the returned JSON into the variable named `data`.
The returned JSON has been generated within PHP through:
`echo json_encode(array('message'=>0);`.

Back in my javascript console I'm logging the output of `data` with `console.log(data);`. The output is `{"message":0}`, which seems correct.

However, if I try to log `console.log(data.message);` I am getting `message: undefined`.

What am I doing wrong in accessing this pretty basic JSON object?

I've been reading some articles about how to move through JSON object, e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_overview.htm but I can't find my mistake.

Hopefully you can point me into the right direction :)

Thank you :)

Comment: In PHP it should be `json_encode()`

Comment: Your absolutely right. That's what I am using :)

Comment: Check your code. You wrote `encode_json`.

Comment: Fixed it in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do `JSON.parse(result)` first to make it an object, because at the moment you're trying to access `message` property of a string.

You know there are 2 JSON functions in javascript, right...?

```
// returns string representation of the object
JSON.stringify(object);

// returns a new object built from the string
JSON.parse(object_stringified);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much and thanks for pointing out those two functions :)